# Import properties file to all projects in solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msbuild

I have C++ solution which consists of 78 projects. I need to import property file to all projects. The quick and dirty answer is to add to all 78 project files the following section (using `sed` or similar tool):

```
<Import Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\VersionProj\Version.proj')" 
   Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\VersionProj\Version.proj" />
```

What is the best way to perform import without modifying project files?

Comment: I think this doesn't make sense, because SLN is very little more than a list of projects, and it doesn't know anything about msbuild.  But If you want a creative solution which is totally not worth the time but is at least in tune with the role of the SLN system, you could read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165951.aspx about how projects are loaded out of the sln and make your own project type which would wrap the normal vcxproj loader and insert a secret project reference somehow after loading the vcxproj.

Comment: You call that 'quick and dirty' but is it really *dirty*? Suppose you take out one project or a couple of them and want to use them standalone or in another solution: if those projects would not be specifying their imports themselves, but instead on a solution level, that info is lost when moving them out of the solution. Which, as @zeromus points out, is after all merely a list of things to build.

Comment: Let's consider an analogy. On unix you might be able to meddle with the system's `make` to cause it to operate on a makefile which imports what you want, and then imports the original argument. What's the equivalent? It would be changing the msbuild.exe that visual studio runs. This should be possible by--uh... editing the ToolsVersion in the vcxproj. Yes, believe it or not, the SLN doesnt even which msbuild.exe to use until it loads the vcxproj. And yet you want to issue an msbuild command from the sln to the vcxproj? Hopefully you can see how quixotic this is.